# Listing all specs in order determined by seed in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've noticed a couple specs that are failing intermittently depending on the order they're run.

To isolate them I'm looking for a command where I can enter the seed number and see all the specs listed with line numbers in the order determined by the seed number.  Is this possible? using --format=documentation did not provide the info needed.

From there I will note the list of tests run BEFORE the intermittent failure each time it occurs and eventually narrow down to my culprit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

RSpec's JSON formatter outputs the filenames and line numbers in the order they were run:

```
rspec --seed 1 -f json > out.json
```

To get just the list of filenames with line numbers from the resulting `out.json` file:

```
require 'json'
data = JSON.parse(File.read('out.json'))
examples = data['examples'].map do |example| 
  "#{example['file_path']}:#{example['line_number']}"
end
```

Now `examples` will contain an array of file paths like:

```
["./spec/models/user_spec.rb:19", "spec/models/user_spec.rb:29"]
```

Comment: Much better than what I was doing.  Is there a good method for selecting the preceding examples once I identify the first failure: if example['status'] == 'failed'?

Comment: You can also add `--dry-run` to the rspec command to get this report without actually running the specs.

Answer (score 3):

In my `spec/spec_helper.rb` file:

I have created a global variable `$files_executed` and initialized it to an empty set:

```
require 'set'
$files_executed = Set.new
```

Then, inside the `RSpec.configure` block I added:

```
config.before(:each) do |example|
  $files_executed.add example.file_path
end
```

And this:

```
config.after(:suite) do
  files_filename = 'files_executed.txt'
  File.write(files_filename, $files_executed.to_a.join(' '))
end
```

And then you can use the content of the file `files_executed.txt` to feed the `rspec` command again with the order that was used before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`--bisect` option](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/bisect).

> RSpec's `--order random` and `--seed` options help surface flickering examples that only fail when one or more other examples are executed first. It can be very difficult to isolate the exact combination of examples that triggers the failure. The `--bisect` flag helps solve that problem.